# Deployment Heroku, Build stopping after webpack bundles on heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, webpack, deployment, ejs

Not sure how to set up my environment to get my MERN application deployed on Heroku. I'm using EJS and webpack. When I deploy the application it is currently staying stuck at the webpack build phase:

```
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  12.18.3
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 12.18.3...
       Downloading and installing node 12.18.3...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.6
       
-----> Restoring cache
       Cached directories were not restored due to a change in version of node, npm, yarn or stack
       Module installation may take longer for this build
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       
       > fsevents@1.2.13 install /tmp/build_31a40992/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/fsevents
       > node install.js
       
       
       Skipping 'fsevents' build as platform linux is not supported
       
       > nodemon@1.19.4 postinstall /tmp/build_31a40992/node_modules/nodemon
       > node bin/postinstall || exit 0
       
       Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
        > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate
       
       
       > bcrypt@5.0.1 install /tmp/build_31a40992/node_modules/bcrypt
       > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
       
       [bcrypt] Success: "/tmp/build_31a40992/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node" is installed via remote
       added 1003 packages in 7.872s
       
-----> Build
       Running build
       
       > project@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_31a40992
       > webpack --mode production
       
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db
Why you should do it regularly:
https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
       asset App.js 592 KiB [compared for emit] [minimized] [big] (name: main) 1 related asset
       orphan modules 10.6 KiB [orphan] 3 modules
       runtime modules 663 bytes 3 modules
       modules by path ./node_modules/ 142 KiB
         modules by path ./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 5.02 KiB 6 modules
         modules by path ./node_modules/react/ 6.48 KiB 2 modules
         modules by path ./node_modules/react-dom/ 119 KiB 2 modules
         modules by path ./node_modules/scheduler/ 4.91 KiB 2 modules
         modules by path ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 3.85 KiB 2 modules
         ./node_modules/object-assign/index.js 2.06 KiB [built] [code generated]
       modules by path ./src/ 18.3 KiB
         ./src/App.jsx + 3 modules 17.2 KiB [built] [code generated]
         ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/styles/PricesComponent.css 1.1 KiB [built] [code generated]
       
       WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
       This can impact web performance.
       Assets: 
         App.js (592 KiB)
       
       WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
       Entrypoints:
         main (583 KiB)
             BuyOrders.js
       
       WARNING in webpack performance recommendations: 
       You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
       For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
       
       webpack 5.67.0 compiled with 3 warnings in 33959 ms
       
       asset Edit.js 580 KiB [compared for emit] [minimized] [big] (name: main) 1 related asset
       runtime modules 663 bytes 3 modules
       orphan modules 1.13 KiB [orphan] 1 module
       modules by path ./node_modules/ 142 KiB
         modules by path ./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 5.02 KiB 6 modules
         modules by path ./node_modules/react/ 6.48 KiB 2 modules
         modules by path ./node_modules/react-dom/ 119 KiB 2 modules
         modules by path ./node_modules/scheduler/ 4.91 KiB 2 modules
         modules by path ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 3.85 KiB 2 modules
         ./node_modules/object-assign/index.js 2.06 KiB [built] [code generated]
       modules by path ./src/ 14.8 KiB
         ./src/AppDep/Edit.jsx + 1 modules 12.2 KiB [built] [code generated]
         ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/styles/Edit.css 2.64 KiB [built] [code generated]
       
       WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
       This can impact web performance.
       Assets: 
         Edit.js (580 KiB)
       
       WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
       Entrypoints:
         main (580 KiB)
             Edit.js
       
       WARNING in webpack performance recommendations: 
       You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
       For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
       
       webpack 5.67.0 compiled with 3 warnings in 33955 ms
       
       asset MakeBuy.js 572 KiB [compared for emit] [minimized] [big] (name: main) 1 related asset
       runtime modules 663 bytes 3 modules
       orphan modules 1.13 KiB [orphan] 1 module
       modules by path ./node_modules/ 142 KiB
         modules by path ./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 5.02 KiB 6 modules
         modules by path ./node_modules/react/ 6.48 KiB 2 modules
         modules by path ./node_modules/react-dom/ 119 KiB 2 modules
         modules by path ./node_modules/scheduler/ 4.91 KiB 2 modules
         modules by path ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 3.85 KiB 2 modules
         ./node_modules/object-assign/index.js 2.06 KiB [built] [code generated]
       modules by path ./src/ 9.07 KiB
         ./src/AppDep/MakeBuy.jsx + 1 modules 8.12 KiB [built] [code generated]
         ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/styles/Make.css 975 bytes [built] [code generated]
       
       WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
       This can impact web performance.
       Assets: 
         MakeBuy.js (572 KiB)
       
       WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
       Entrypoints:
         main (572 KiB)
             MakeBuy.js
       
       WARNING in webpack performance recommendations: 
       You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
       For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
       
       webpack 5.67.0 compiled with 3 warnings in 33960 ms
       
       asset MakeSell.js 572 KiB [compared for emit] [minimized] [big] (name: main) 1 related asset
       runtime modules 663 bytes 3 modules
       orphan modules 1.13 KiB [orphan] 1 module
       modules by path ./node_modules/ 142 KiB
         modules by path ./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 5.02 KiB 6 modules
         modules by path ./node_modules/react/ 6.48 KiB 2 modules
         modules by path ./node_modules/react-dom/ 119 KiB 2 modules
         modules by path ./node_modules/scheduler/ 4.91 KiB 2 modules
         modules by path ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 3.85 KiB 2 modules
         ./node_modules/object-assign/index.js 2.06 KiB [built] [code generated]
       modules by path ./src/ 9.48 KiB
         ./src/AppDep/MakeSell.jsx + 1 modules 8.53 KiB [built] [code generated]
         ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/styles/Make.css 975 bytes [built] [code generated]
       
       WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
       This can impact web performance.
       Assets: 
         MakeSell.js (572 KiB)
       
       WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
       Entrypoints:
         main (572 KiB)
             MakeSell.js
       
       WARNING in webpack performance recommendations: 
       You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
       For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
       
       webpack 5.67.0 compiled with 3 warnings in 34225 ms
       
       asset MyOrders.js 665 KiB [compared for emit] [minimized] [big] (name: main) 1 related asset
       orphan modules 531 KiB [orphan] 266 modules
       runtime modules 663 bytes 3 modules
       cacheable modules 212 KiB
         modules by path ./node_modules/ 142 KiB 15 modules
         modules by path ./src/ 70.3 KiB
           ./src/AppDep/MyOrders.jsx + 12 modules 59.7 KiB [built] [code generated]
           ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/styles/MyOrders.css 1.11 KiB [built] [code generated]
           ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/styles/Order.css 710 bytes [built] [code generated]
           ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/styles/Matches.css 1.17 KiB [built] [code generated]
           ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/styles/Edit.css 2.64 KiB [built] [code generated]
           + 2 modules
       
       WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
       This can impact web performance.
       Assets: 
         MyOrders.js (665 KiB)
       
       WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
       Entrypoints:
         main (665 KiB)
             MyOrders.js
       
       WARNING in webpack performance recommendations: 
       You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
       For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
       
       webpack 5.67.0 compiled with 3 warnings in 37873 ms
       
       asset Order.js 603 KiB [compared for emit] [minimized] [big] (name: main) 1 related asset
       orphan modules 501 KiB [orphan] 259 modules
       runtime modules 663 bytes 3 modules
       cacheable modules 174 KiB
         modules by path ./node_modules/ 142 KiB
           modules by path ./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 5.02 KiB 6 modules
           modules by path ./node_modules/react/ 6.48 KiB 2 modules
           modules by path ./node_modules/react-dom/ 119 KiB 2 modules
           modules by path ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 3.85 KiB 2 modules
           modules by path ./node_modules/scheduler/ 4.91 KiB 2 modules
           + 1 module
         modules by path ./src/ 32.8 KiB
           ./src/AppDep/Order.jsx + 5 modules 26.8 KiB [built] [code generated]
           ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/styles/Order.css 710 bytes [built] [code generated]
           ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/styles/Edit.css 2.64 KiB [built] [code generated]
           ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/styles/Form.css 2.71 KiB [built] [code generated]
       
       WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
       This can impact web performance.
       Assets: 
         Order.js (603 KiB)
       
       WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
       Entrypoints:
         main (603 KiB)
             Order.js
       
       WARNING in webpack performance recommendations: 
       You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
       For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
       
       webpack 5.67.0 compiled with 3 warnings in 37116 ms
       
       asset Prices.js 34.5 KiB [compared for emit] [minimized] (name: main) 1 related asset
       modules by path ./node_modules/react/ 6.48 KiB
         ./node_modules/react/index.js 190 bytes [built] [code generated]
         ./node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js 6.3 KiB [built] [code generated]
       ./src/AppDep/Prices.jsx 3.99 KiB [built] [code generated]
       ./node_modules/object-assign/index.js 2.06 KiB [built] [code generated]
       webpack 5.67.0 compiled successfully in 11248 ms
       
       asset PricesComponent.js 69 KiB [compared for emit] [minimized] (name: main) 1 related asset
       runtime modules 663 bytes 3 modules
       orphan modules 5.14 KiB [orphan] 2 modules
       modules by path ./node_modules/ 17.4 KiB
         modules by path ./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 5.02 KiB 6 modules
         modules by path ./node_modules/react/ 6.48 KiB
           ./node_modules/react/index.js 190 bytes [built] [code generated]
           ./node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js 6.3 KiB [built] [code generated]
         modules by path ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 3.85 KiB
           ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/cssWithMappingToString.js 2.28 KiB [built] [code generated]
           ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js 1.57 KiB [built] [code generated]
         ./node_modules/object-assign/index.js 2.06 KiB [built] [code generated]
       modules by path ./src/ 11.7 KiB
         ./src/AppDep/PricesComponent.jsx + 2 modules 10.6 KiB [built] [code generated]
         ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/styles/PricesComponent.css 1.1 KiB [built] [code generated]
       webpack 5.67.0 compiled successfully in 11402 ms
       
       asset SellOrders.js 583 KiB [compared for emit] [minimized] [big] (name: main) 1 related asset
       runtime modules 663 bytes 3 modules
       orphan modules 6.42 KiB [orphan] 2 modules
       modules by path ./node_modules/ 142 KiB
         modules by path ./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 5.02 KiB 6 modules
         modules by path ./node_modules/react/ 6.48 KiB 2 modules
         modules by path ./node_modules/react-dom/ 119 KiB 2 modules
         modules by path ./node_modules/scheduler/ 4.91 KiB 2 modules
         modules by path ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 3.85 KiB 2 modules
         ./node_modules/object-assign/index.js 2.06 KiB [built] [code generated]
       modules by path ./src/ 20 KiB
         ./src/AppDep/SellOrders.jsx + 2 modules 17.4 KiB [built] [code generated]
         ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/styles/SellOrders.css 2.6 KiB [built] [code generated]
       
       WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
       This can impact web performance.
       Assets: 
         SellOrders.js (583 KiB)
       
       WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
       Entrypoints:
         main (583 KiB)
             SellOrders.js
       
       WARNING in webpack performance recommendations: 
       You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
       For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
       
       webpack 5.67.0 compiled with 3 warnings in 33961 ms
       
       asset Navigation.js 75.3 KiB [compared for emit] [minimized] (name: main) 1 related asset
       runtime modules 663 bytes 3 modules
       orphan modules 1.15 KiB [orphan] 1 module
       modules by path ./node_modules/ 17.4 KiB
         modules by path ./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 5.02 KiB 6 modules
         modules by path ./node_modules/react/ 6.48 KiB
           ./node_modules/react/index.js 190 bytes [built] [code generated]
           ./node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js 6.3 KiB [built] [code generated]
         modules by path ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 3.85 KiB
           ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/cssWithMappingToString.js 2.28 KiB [built] [code generated]
           ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js 1.57 KiB [built] [code generated]
         ./node_modules/object-assign/index.js 2.06 KiB [built] [code generated]
       modules by path ./src/ 11 KiB
         ./src/AppDep/Navigation.jsx + 1 modules 6.73 KiB [built] [code generated]
         ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/styles/Navigation.css 4.27 KiB [built] [code generated]
       webpack 5.67.0 compiled successfully in 11400 ms
       
       asset MatcheRow.js 69.4 KiB [compared for emit] [minimized] (name: main) 1 related asset
       runtime modules 663 bytes 3 modules
       orphan modules 1.14 KiB [orphan] 1 module
       modules by path ./node_modules/ 17.4 KiB
         modules by path ./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 5.02 KiB 6 modules
         modules by path ./node_modules/react/ 6.48 KiB
           ./node_modules/react/index.js 190 bytes [built] [code generated]
           ./node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js 6.3 KiB [built] [code generated]
         modules by path ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 3.85 KiB
           ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/cssWithMappingToString.js 2.28 KiB [built] [code generated]
           ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js 1.57 KiB [built] [code generated]
         ./node_modules/object-assign/index.js 2.06 KiB [built] [code generated]
       modules by path ./src/ 8.09 KiB
         ./src/AppDep/MatcheRow.jsx + 1 modules 5.82 KiB [built] [code generated]
         ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/styles/MatcheRow.css 2.27 KiB [built] [code generated]
       webpack 5.67.0 compiled successfully in 11399 ms
```

So ... webpack 5.67.0 compiled successfully in 11399 ms

but ... I ideally want to run

```
npm run server
```

after the build.

As a reference a successful MERN deployment on heroku should look like this:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 14.x...
       Downloading and installing node 14.18.3...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.15
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       added 538 packages in 5.08s
       
-----> Build
       Running build
       
       > deploy-react-webpack@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_8c86a15a
       > webpack --mode production
       
       asset main.js 129 KiB [emitted] [minimized] (name: main) 1 related asset
       asset ./index.html 278 bytes [emitted]
       modules by path ./node_modules/react/ 6.48 KiB
         ./node_modules/react/index.js 190 bytes [built] [code generated]
         ./node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js 6.3 KiB [built] [code generated]
       modules by path ./node_modules/react-dom/ 119 KiB
         ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js 1.33 KiB [built] [code generated]
         ./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.production.min.js 118 KiB [built] [code generated]
       modules by path ./node_modules/scheduler/ 4.91 KiB
         ./node_modules/scheduler/index.js 198 bytes [built] [code generated]
         ./node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.production.min.js 4.72 KiB [built] [code generated]
       ./src/index.js 3.64 KiB [built] [code generated]
       ./node_modules/object-assign/index.js 2.06 KiB [built] [code generated]
       webpack 5.67.0 compiled successfully in 3745 ms
       
-----> Caching build
       - node_modules
       
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       removed 473 packages and audited 64 packages in 2.943s
       
       2 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       
       
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 34.2M
-----> Launching...
       Released v3
       https://morning-sands-39344.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Any ideas what is the issue?

These are my main setup files

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path')

// module.exports = {
//   entry: './public/App.js',

//   output: {
//     filename: 'App.js',
//     path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
//   },
//   watch: true,
//   mode: 'development',
  
// }

var config = {
  watch: true,
  mode: 'development',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: [/\.js$/, /\.jsx$/],
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              ["@babel/preset-env", {
                "targets": {
                  "ie": "11",
                  "edge": "15",
                  "safari": "10",
                  "firefox": "50",
                  "chrome": "49"
                }
              }],
              "@babel/preset-react"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool : 'inline-source-map',
};

var fooConfig = Object.assign({}, config, {
  //name: "a",
  entry: './src/App.jsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'App.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/dist'),
  },
});
var barConfig = Object.assign({}, config,{
  entry: './src/Databases.jsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'Databases.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/dist'),
  },
});
var booConfig = Object.assign({}, config,{
  entry: './src/Matches.jsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'Matches.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/dist'),
  },
});
var Config1 = Object.assign({}, config,{
  entry: './src/AppDep/BuyOrders.jsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'BuyOrders.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/dist/AppDep'),
  },
});
var Config2 = Object.assign({}, config,{
  entry: './src/AppDep/Edit.jsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'Edit.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/dist/AppDep'),
  },
});
var Config3 = Object.assign({}, config,{
  entry: './src/AppDep/MakeBuy.jsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'MakeBuy.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/dist/AppDep'),
  },
});
var Config4 = Object.assign({}, config,{
  entry: './src/AppDep/MakeSell.jsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'MakeSell.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/dist/AppDep'),
  },
});
var Config5 = Object.assign({}, config,{
  entry: './src/AppDep/MyOrders.jsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'MyOrders.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/dist/AppDep'),
  },
});
var Config6 = Object.assign({}, config,{
  entry: './src/AppDep/Order.jsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'Order.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/dist/AppDep'),
  },
});
var Config7 = Object.assign({}, config,{
  entry: './src/AppDep/Prices.jsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'Prices.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/dist/AppDep'),
  },
});
var Config8 = Object.assign({}, config,{
  entry: './src/AppDep/PricesComponent.jsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'PricesComponent.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/dist/AppDep'),
  },
});
var Config9 = Object.assign({}, config,{
  entry: './src/AppDep/SellOrders.jsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'SellOrders.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/dist/AppDep'),
  },
});
var Config10 = Object.assign({}, config,{
  entry: './src/AppDep/Navigation.jsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'Navigation.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/dist/AppDep'),
  },
});
var Config11 = Object.assign({}, config,{
  entry: './src/AppDep/MatcheRow.jsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'MatcheRow.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/dist/AppDep'),
  },
});


// Return Array of Configurations
module.exports = [
  fooConfig, barConfig, booConfig, Config1, Config2, Config3, Config4, Config5, Config6, Config7, Config8, Config9, Config10, Config11
];
```

Thanks

Comment: If I am not mistaken, You created a react project and want to deploy on heroku?

Answer (score 1):

Heroku uses Procfiles or the start command to start your server. Add a start command at the script section in your package.json that points to your nodejs server.

```
"script": {
  "start": "node pathtoyourserver.js"
}
```

Or you can add a Procfile

```
web: node pathtoyourserver.js
```

or use your npm command

```
web: npm run server
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support